# Is it possible to get value from Summernote editor in asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, summernote

I'm using summernote editor, and I want to retrieve its content in code behind.
I tried to use the following ways , but it returns empty(null)

1-

default.aspx

```
<div class="summernote"  id="txtTest" runat="server"></div>
```

Code behind:

```
string content= txtTest.InnerText;
```

2-

default.aspx

```
<div class="summernote"  id="txtTest" ></div>
```

Code behind:

```
string name = Request.Form["txtTest"];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a `<textarea>` to handle this as opposed to a `<div>`? Usually they are a bit easier to use with respect to storing values (as they are designed to do so) :

```
<textarea id="txtTest" runat="server"></textarea>
```

One of the ways that you might handle this would be to register an event using [Summernote's available API](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/#api) to set the HTML content for your `<textarea>` element whenever focus was lost (e.g. the `onblur`) :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Set up your summernote instance
        $("#txtTest").summernote();
        // When the summernote instance loses focus, update the content of your <textarea>
        $("#txtTest").on('summernote.blur', function () {
            $('#txtTest').html($('#txtTest').summernote('code'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Since you are likely going to be storing HTML content within the element, you'll likely want to ensure that .NET doesn't think you are trying to exploit it. You can do this by either explicitly setting this page to ignore that process by updating the [`ValidateRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your page :

```
<%@ Page ... ValidateRequest = "false" %>
```

Or you could try simply escaping the content that is being set :

```
$('#txtTest').html(escape($('#txtTest').summernote('code')));
```

Comment: Rion, I have this same issue, and when I change my div to a textarea per your suggestion, I do get the text in the codebehind, but I lose ALL the styling to the Summernote editor.  The button bar is gone, and all i have is a very small resizable textfield. How do I get the textarea to style the same as the div?

Comment: UPDATE: Got it!!  This is a great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here is My code Working Perfectly

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSummernote" runat="server" Text="Image" AssociatedControlID="txtSummernote" CssClass="control-label col-md-3"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummernote" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text="Summernote"></asp:Label>
      </div>
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script src="/Content/SummerNote/summernote.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Set up your summernote instance
            $("#<%= txtSummernote.ClientID %>").summernote();
            focus: true
            // When the summernote instance loses focus, update the content of your <textarea>
            $("#<%= txtSummernote.ClientID %>").on('summernote.blur', function () {
                $('#<%= txtSummernote.ClientID %>').html($('#<%= txtSummernote.ClientID %>').summernote('code'));
           });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function funcMyHtml() {
            debugger;
            document.getElementById("#<%= txtSummernote.ClientID %>").value = $('#<%= txtSummernote.ClientID %>').summernote('code');
        }
    </script>
```

C# Code behind

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSum.Text = txtSummernote.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it working.
ref it as a class
class="summernote"

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.summernote').summernote();
    });
```